# C++ std::array cast

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have 4 classes: `Foundation`, `FoundationWidget`,  `Game` and `GameWidget`. `FoundationWidget` extends `Foundation` and `GameWidget` extends `Game`.

`Game` also contains an std::array of `Foundation`s and `GameWidget` contains an std::array of `FoundationWidget`s. `Game` also contains a virtual method, which should return the pointer to the array of `Foundation`s. `GameWidget` overrides this method by returning a pointer to the array of its `FoundationWidget`s.
The current (non-working) implementation looks like this:

```
class Game {
    std::array<Foundation, 4> foundations;
private:
    virtual std::array<Foundation, 4>* get_foundations() {
        return &this->foundations;
    }
}

class GameWidget : public Game {
    std::array<FoundationWidget, 4> foundations;
private:
    std::array<Foundation, 4>* get_foundations() {
        return &this->foundations;
    }
}
```

I'd expect this to work, since it's an array of the same size with class, that extends the one specified as return type, but instead I'm getting this error: `cannot convert ‘std::array<FoundationWidget, 4ul>*’ to ‘std::array<Foundation, 4ul>*’ in return`.

I've also tried to declare the class attributes as arrays of pointers, but the result was the same. Neither static_cast or dynamic_cast helped.

What am I missing here? Is there any way to cast arrays? If not, can I use some construction to get the same results, i.e. "virtual" class members?

Comment: If `FoundationWidget` inherits from `Foundation` why not just have a `std::array<Foundation*, 4>`(or some other pointer type in `GameWidget`?

Comment: also, you return `std::array<Foundation, 4>*` which is a pointer type,if you are considering something like getter, you should be careful not return a temporary/local variable's pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank for your comment. By the time, I have resolved it this way, but I'm still curious about the casting.

Comment: @appleapple Both get methods are in fact private. I've edited the example.

Comment: @sveatlo A `Foo<Bar>` is a complete different type from `Foo<Baz>` even if `Baz` is derived from `Bar`.  There is no conversion between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are packed values of a certain type of data.

Arrays of different types are not compatible as arrays.  Their size can differ, for example.  And arrays are packed, so an array of elements of size 7 and an array of elements of size 8 are not going to work.

Even if they are the same size, C++ dictates the arrays are not convertible.

You can fix this by having `array<unique_ptr<Base>, N>` -- arrays of (smart) pointers.  One could also write a type erasure `any_derived<Base, size_limit>` type and have an `array<any_derived<Base, size_limit>, N>` and store them contiguously, if you want to avoid the extra fragmentation and allocations.

But really just use `unique_ptr`.

```
using foundations_t = std::array<std::unique_ptr<Foundation>, 4>;
template<class T> struct tag_t {};
struct HasFoundation {
  foundations_t foundations;
  HasFoundation( tag_t<T> ) {
    std::generate(foundations.begin(), foundations.end(), []{return std::make_unique<T>(); } );
  }
  HasFoundation(HasFoundation const&)=delete;
  HasFoundation(HasFoundation&&)=default;
  HasFoundation& operator=(HasFoundation const&)=delete;
  HasFoundation& operator=(HasFoundation&&)=default;
};
class Game:HasFoundation {
protected:
  template<class T>
  Game(tag_t<T> tag):HasFoundation(tag){}
public:
  Game():Game(tag_t<Foundation>{}) {}
  virtual foundations_t* get_foundations() {
    return &this->foundations;
  }
};

class GameWidget : public Game {
public:
  GameWidget():Game(tag_t<FoundationWidget>{}) {}
};
```

here we have one storage class, and what it stores is determined at construction time.

A template version would require all logic in `Game` be exposed in header files.  This one instead requires that all access to the "real" type of the `foundations` elements requires runtime dispatch.

Comment: note that using `array<unique_ptr<Foundation>, 4>`, the array is initialised with empty `unique_ptr`s, whereas OP's value array had default constructed `Foundation`s and `FoundationWidget`s. A `generate(foundations.begin(), foundations.end(), make_unique<Foundation>);` call will initialise the Foundations

Comment: @Caleth That generate isn't quite enough, as you cannot copy unique pointers.  I think you are missing a lambda.  I mean, aren't we all?

Comment: a lambda will definatly work, but iirc generate doesn't copy, it assigns http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate "The type Ret must be such that an object of type ForwardIt can be dereferenced and assigned a value of type Ret." Were you thinking of `std::fill`?

Comment: @Caleth Ah, I missed the lack of `()`.  I thougth you where calling it, not passing a pointer-to.  I'm slightly surprised that that isn't ambiguous, but only slightly.

Answer (score 1):

A `GameWidget` object contains an array of 4 `FoundationWidget` objects and also a different array of 4 `Foundation` objects (indirectly via its base class subobject). If this is what you want, fine. I somehow doubt it and going to assume you do want something else, though the issue of containment is unrelated to the issue of the return type of `get_foundations()`.

Regardless of what object contains which array, these two array types do not form covariant return types. Only classes related by inheritance and pointers/references to such classes may form covariant return types. `std::array`s of such classes and pointers to such arrays and arrays *of* pointers to such classes etc are not related by inheritance themselves and cannot be used covariantly. So your expectations unfortunately have no support in reality.

There is also no way to reliably cast arrays of such objects.

There are several ways to achieve what you want, some more involved than others.

1. Make `Game` a template.

   ```
   template <class F>
   class Game {
       std::array<F, 4> foundations;
   private:
       virtual std::array<F, 4>* get_foundations() {
           return &this->foundations;
       }
   };

   class GameWidget : public Game<FoundationWidget> {
       // nothing here!
   };
   ```
2. Do not expose arrays.

   ```
   class Game {
       virtual Foundation* get_foundation (int) = 0;
   };

   class GameWidget : public Game {
       FoundationWidget* get_foundation (int i) {
          return &foundations[i];
       }
       std::array<FoundationWidget, 4> foundations;
   };
   ```
3. Create a family of custom containers for foundations such that `FoundationWidgetArray` inherits `FoundationArray` (this is probably too long to show here).